# C is it possible to function return a constant size array

Tags: arrays, c, memory

I have this code:

```c
byte SpriteSheetGetSprite4() {
    byte a[6];
    ... there "a" is being set ...
    return a;
}[6]; // <--
```

I'm using Visual Studio and it says that this is ok, but does it actually work properly? Do I need `free()`, when I use it?

Comment: Even if you could return an array, the indexes go from 0 to 5, you can't access `[6]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an array in C. You could return a pointer, though.

```c
#define MALLOC( t, n ) ( ( t* )malloc( sizeof( t ) * ( n ) ) )

byte *SpriteSheetGetSprite4() {
   byte *a = MALLOC( byte, 6 );
   if ( !a )
      return NULL;

   ...

   return a;
}
```

Elsewhere,

```c
byte *a = SpriteSheetGetSprite4();
if ( !a ) {
   ...
}

...

free( a );
```